# Non isomorphic graphs - how to draw

Tags: graph-theory

I have been asked to draw all the non-isomorphic connected simple graphs, each with a degree sequence (2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4) I understand a non isomorphic graph is a graph where the relabelling of the vertices wont give the same graph. But I am lost to where to even start, or the best way to go about it.

Help

URL=http://s906.photobucket.com/user/michael_lews23/media/nonisomorphic_zps280581a7.jpg.html

Sent it last night, but would these be classed as non isomorphic?

Answer (score 3):

One way you can approach this problem is noting that the vertices with degree 2 can be "reduced" to an edge without changing degrees. So we want to find all non-isomorphic connected simple graphs with degrees (3,3,3,3,4,4) first. Consider the complement of this graph; you get (1,1,2,2,2,2) as the degrees. There are only a few ways in which this can happen: you can have a lone edge and a 4-cycle, a 3-path and a 3-cycle, or a 6-path. (I believe these are the only cases)

Next, convert these back into graphs and the question is reduced to finding edges (which could be the same edge, giving a 3-long "edge") to "lengthen" by inserting a vertex in the middle.